# Terminology in EF and Linq

Tags: linq, entity-framework, terminology

I am not a programmer in real life, I just learn it for fun and to pass my free time. So I am kinda away from programmers` environment and always have problems with terminology, so please forgive my ignorance if my question was too easy.

Can someone tell me if I am right or wrong here:

[image]

1. Context
2. ???
3. Entity

Am I right? and what's number 2 called?

Comment: 2: entity collection or table from the context

Comment: Technically, it's a DbSet, which is probably misnamed.. it should be an EntitySet or DbEntitySet, as in a set of entities.  A set is a type of collection.  #3 is actually an IQueryable result, since you did not specify a statement that returns a single item.  If you said .Where().Single() it would be an entity that was returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Context
2. Entity Collection
3. Query result / collection

Comment: So what is entity? I thought it is the object that holds the data?

Comment: @MIH: Yes, for a single row/object.  You don't have any in that code.  (you probably want to call `First()` rather than `Where()`)

Comment: Yup, I was just making a smaple code, I missed that :) thanks